# Match if a column partially matches another column

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I am trying to compare columns of the same file. The table looks like this:

```
  G  A  AA  GG CC TT CT
  C  T  CC  TT GG GG AA
```

What I want to do is to compare the first and second column with the rest, and see if they contain part of the first or second column.

Something like this:

```
awk '$1 == ^$3 || $2 == ^$3 {print $0}' File.txt
```

or like this

```
awk '$1 ~ /$3/ || $2 ~ /$3/ {print $0}' File.txt
```

But is not working. How can I make these kinds of comparisons between columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your comparisons backwards.  Try these alternatives instead:

```
awk '$3 ~ $1 || $3 ~ $2 { print }' inputfile
awk 'match( $3, $1 ) || match( $3, $2 ) { print }' inputfile
```

In your sample code, you were trying `$1 ~ $3` which expands to `C ~ /CC/` (does the expression `/CC/` match the string `C`?) rather than `CC ~ /C/` (does the expression `/C/` match the string `CC`?).

Comment: Thank you but It is not working.

Comment: Define 'not working'?  It works for me given your extremely limited sample data in the post.

Comment: It is working, sorry I did something wrong.

Comment: No worries; glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) if (match($i,$1) || match($i,$2)) { print; next } }' file
G A AA GG CC TT CT
C T CC TT GG GG AA
```

Testing on a file where we the test fails for two lines and succeeds for two lines:

```
$ cat file
G A AA GG CC TT CT
C T AG AA GG GG AA
G C AA AA TT TT AT
C T CC TT GG GG AA

$ awk '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i) if (match($i,$1) || match($i,$2)) { print; next } }' file
G A AA GG CC TT CT
C T CC TT GG GG AA
```

The `awk` script goes through all columns from column 3 onwards and compares each column with column 1 and 2.  If the character in column 1 or 2 is present in any of the other columns, the line is immediately printed and the script continues with the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try (with data stolen from Kusalananda's sample)

```
awk '{PAT = "[" $1 $2 "]"} gsub (PAT, "&") > 2' file
G A AA GG CC TT CT
C T CC TT GG GG AA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach:

```
grep -P '^(\S+) (\S+) .*(\1|\2)' gene.file
```